# Is there a simpler way than to pass a 40-object table?

Tags: lua

I'm running these requests for numbers with five sub-cases which have four sub-cases each. There are over 200 of these cases, of which just one is shown below, so it would be several thousand lines of code. (This is example code, the numbers would not all be the same, of course.)

```
  elseif case1 then
                      if u <= 0 then if w == 0 then return B(2,3), B(3,4)
                                 elseif w == 1 then return B(2,3), B(3,4)
                                 elseif w == 2 then return B(2,3), B(3,4)
                                 elseif w >= 3 then return B(2,3), B(3,4)
               elseif if u == 1 then return LimitCheck(if w == 0 then return B(2,3), B(3,4)
                                 elseif w == 1 then return B(2,3), B(3,4)
                                 elseif w == 2 then return B(2,3), B(3,4)
                                 elseif w >= 3 then return B(2,3), B(3,4)
               elseif if u == 2 then return LimitCheck(if w == 0 then return B(2,3), B(3,4)
                                 elseif w == 1 then return B(2,3), B(3,4)
                                 elseif w == 2 then return B(2,3), B(3,4)
                                 elseif w >= 3 then return B(2,3), B(3,4)
               elseif if u == 3 then return LimitCheck(if w == 0 then return B(2,3), B(3,4)
                                 elseif w == 1 then return B(2,3), B(3,4)
                                 elseif w == 2 then return B(2,3), B(3,4)
                                 elseif w >= 3 then return B(2,3), B(3,4)
               elseif if u == 4 then return LimitCheck(if w == 0 then return B(2,3), B(3,4)
                                 elseif w == 1 then return B(2,3), B(3,4)
                                 elseif w == 2 then return B(2,3), B(3,4)
                                 elseif w >= 3 then return B(2,3), B(3,4)
```

I thought I'd be clever and compartmentalize the code that repeats, let sub-functions take apart the cases:

```
  local function LimitCheck(arg)
    if w <= 0 then return arg[1], arg[2]
    elseif w == 1 then return arg[3], arg[4]
    elseif w == 2 then return arg[5], arg[6]
    elseif w >= 3 then return arg[7], arg[8]
    end
  end
  local function Limits(arg)
    if u == 0 then return LimitCheck({arg[1],arg[2],arg[3],arg[4],arg[5],arg[6],arg[7],arg[8],})
    elseif u == 1 then return LimitCheck({arg[9],arg[10],arg[11],arg[12],arg[13],arg[14],arg[15],arg[16],})
    elseif u == 2 then return LimitCheck({arg[17],arg[18],arg[19],arg[20],arg[21],arg[22],arg[23],arg[24],})
    elseif u == 3 then return LimitCheck({arg[25],arg[26],arg[27],arg[28],arg[29],arg[30],arg[31],arg[32],})
    elseif u == 4 then return LimitCheck({arg[33],arg[34],arg[35],arg[36],arg[37],arg[38],arg[39],arg[40]})
    end
  end
```

And then have the main function return what it needs to know in one bulk:

```
  elseif case1 then
    return Limits({B(5,6),B(7,8),   B(5,6),B(5,6),  B(5,6),B(5,6),  B(5,6),B(5,6),
                   B(5,6),B(5,6),   B(5,6),B(5,6),  B(5,6),B(5,6),  B(5,6),B(5,6),
                   B(5,6),B(5,6),   B(5,6),B(5,6),  B(5,6),B(5,6),  B(5,6),B(5,6),
                   B(5,6),B(5,6),   B(5,6),B(5,6),  B(5,6),B(5,6),  B(5,6),B(5,6),
                   B(5,6),B(5,6),   B(5,6),B(5,6),  B(5,6),B(5,6),  B(5,6),B(5,6)})
```

Problem is, this is a 40-entry table object that is passed every time, quite a bulky undertaking for a request that may happen 100 times a second. And it returns a bunch of stuff that isn't used.
I wonder if there is a resource-saving way to do this.

Comment: why not use a look up table?

Comment: just out of curiosity, what problem are you actually trying to solve? what needs 200 x 5 x 4 hardcoded conditions checked 100 times per second?

Comment: @Piglet: It's a script for a RTS game. It has about 200 factions who fight battles on a virtual map. I assign them limits to determine who should win. I split this up into 5 stages of development (i.e. later in game the limits are higher), and in each of these stages the limit they get is dependent on how many regions they already have, which is 4 cases. When you hit end turn the game goes through the 200 factions of which two dozen might have a battle, and each time these limits are called for various calculations. It's not literally 100 times per second, but might be that much in a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of how to do this using a lookup table.
You can hardcode it or build it from code if the structure allows it.

```
local LUT = {
  [0] = {
    [0] = "a",
    [1] = "b",
    [2] = "c",
    [3] = "d",
  },
  [1] = {
    [0] = "e",
    [1] = "f",
    [2] = "g",
    [3] = "h",
  },
  [2] = {
    [0] = "i",
    [1] = "j",
    [2] = "k",
    [3] = "l",
  },
  [3] = {
    [0] = "m",
    [1] = "n",
    [2] = "o",
    [3] = "p",
  },
  [4] = {
    [0] = "q",
    [1] = "r",
    [2] = "s",
    [3] = "t",
  },
}

function lookup(u, w)
  -- we only accept u <= 5
  if math.type(u) ~= "integer" or u > 4
   -- and w >= 0
    or math.type(w) ~= "integer" or w < 0 then
    return
  end
  return LUT[math.max(0, u)][math.min(3, w)]
end

print(lookup(-5, 3))
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work for me in my testing. But if I have 100 of these local tables, won't they all have to be created every time I request any of the numbers? Seems like a looot of memory used to get one number. Or does it not matter because any elseif line would have to be loaded into memory in its entirety as well?

Comment: no you're creating this lookup table once and then you just index it. you can of course add more dimensions to this table. memory? you're not running this on a ancient microcontroller... you shoulnd't care about memory unless you have many millions of choices.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I figured out that I can index these tables with true and false. What else would be handy was if I could name these tables in some concatenated way, like local LUT_..getName() = {}. Where getName() returns a string.

Comment: Can these be dynamically accessed, like:
name1 = "tom"
print(_G["LUT_"..name1][1]
I get errors with _g, _M and _ENV if the lookup tables are local. Should I make them global? Your is local above.

Comment: I don't know the structure of your code nor do I understand how you get from my example to what you mention in your comments. yes you can index tables with true and false but your example used integers so why would you want to use booleans now? why do you need so many tables with names? in your example you just had integer conditions. .no names.  I don't know what this has to do with _G, _ENV... my table is local because using locals whenever possible is good practice. there was no reason to use a global.

Comment: Sorry to throw a bunch of different questions at you, I didn't want to clutter the forum with more questions. Forget my comment about the booleans, One of the "dimensions" of my table is whether a faction gets a extra high limit, and that answer is delivered by a function which returns true or false. So if I wanted to use these answers in my table I'd have to put something inbetween that says "if true then 1 else 0", better to just use booleans directly.

Comment: I need that many tables because there are that many factions in the game. When requesting the limit for, say, athens, the table is a different one than for sparta. So the tables would be named LUT_athens, LUT_sparta, etc. The function that gets the limits would request numbers from them. But instead of making an elseif line saying "if you are faction x then take your numbers from table LUT_x", I could directly tell them to look in the table named x. For that I would need to go from a string to a table name. The answers I found claim that _G or _ENV do this. But it doesn't work with locals.

Comment: yes that doesnt work with locals. why don't you add that as an extra dimension to your table? instead of having 100 local tables just use your faction names as table keys. if the top level of your LUT. so you can index it like LUT[faction] to get to its fields LUT.Sparta, LUT.Athens, ...

Comment: Good idea, thanks. (I suppose I didn't want to make it one big object because I thought it was faster if only one relevant table has to be loaded than if a table of all 126 of them every time any number is needed. A big part of this programming learning experience for me is to try to make it elegant and resource-saving, even though that makes no practical difference.)